# undefined method `nil' for #<Admin:0x00000011ead6f0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I'm using rails_admin and I have overrided delete action with adding some line of code:

```
if request.get? # DELETE

   respond_to do |format|
       format.html { render @action.template_name }
       format.js   { render @action.template_name, layout: false }
   end

elsif request.delete? # DESTROY

   redirect_path = nil

   # puts 'CUSTOM DELETE'
   # This code to assign current user that will delete following object.
   # History tracker can not assign current_user by itself.
   if @object.has_attribute?(:updater_id)
      @object.updater = _current_user
      @object.save
   end

   @auditing_adapter && @auditing_adapter.delete_object(@object, @abstract_model, _current_user)
   if @object.destroy
      flash[:success] = t('admin.flash.successful', name: @model_config.label, action: t('admin.actions.delete.done'))
      redirect_path = index_path
   else
      flash[:error] = t('admin.flash.error', name: @model_config.label, action: t('admin.actions.delete.done'))
      redirect_path = back_or_index
   end

   redirect_to redirect_path
 end
```

When the delete action is called it throws:

```
undefined method `nil' for #<Admin:0x00000011ead6f0>
```

Yes that is strange. I always get undefined methods for `nilClasses` but this. This is nil for defined object. This happens on `@object.updater - _current_user` line

`@object` is model that will be destroyed. `_current_user` is logged in `Admin` model.

Why this error is happening?

The models I use are: `Category`, `SubCategory`, `Sub2Category` and `Admin`.
Category has_many SubCategory, SubCategory has_many Sub2Category. Admin is `updater` and `_current_user`.

This error happened when I try to delete `Sub2Category` via rails_admin.

Backtrace:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `nil' for #<Admin:0x00000013b9b960>):
config/initializers/rails_admin_delete_override.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Delete>'
Rendered D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-8b487239e801/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-8b487239e801/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.0ms)
Rendered D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-8b487239e801/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-8b487239e801/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (25.0ms)
Rendered D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.0ms)
Rendered D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.0ms)
Rendered D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.0ms)
Rendered D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (33.0ms)
Rendered D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (1.0ms)
Rendered D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.0ms)
Rendered D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (84.0ms)
```

Comment: What's the backtrace of this error?

Comment: And what line is 40th in your `rails_admin_delete_override.rb` file?

Comment: `@object.updater = _current_user` - this line.

Comment: @MarekLipka could it be because of associations that deleting model has?

Comment: What are these associations?

Comment: How does your whole `rails_admin_delete_override.rb` file look like?

Comment: I think the original method had nil function which your `rails_admin_delete_override.rb` file is calling. Try adding nil function to your admin class.

Comment: I have edited, again. I though the showing whole code is not so good idea.  The main problem is that, it sometime happens and somethime not. Also original delete action does is not so different than mine. My only has has these 4 lines of code with comments.

Comment: @MarekLipka the funny thing is that when I added `nil` method to my `Admin` class, now it gives me `undefined method delete' for nil:NilClass` error at the same line.